# Why is the <nav> element continue in the subsequent lines, although is closed?

Tags: html

I started learning html and I encountered a first problem. If someone can explain me why although the nav element is closed is still continues to be applied to the subsequent elements?

**See the live example..**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.1/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<title>Example Cafe - community cafe in Newguay, Cornwall, UK </title>
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <h1>Introduction</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Recipes</h1>
  </section>
<nav>
<p><a href="recipes.html">Recipes</p>
<p><a href="men.html">Menu</p>
<p><a href="operating_times.html">Operating Times</p>
<p><a href="contact.html">Contact</p>
</nav>
<hr>
 <h1>EXAMPLE CAFE</h1>
<p>Welcome to example cafe, We will be developing this site throughout
the book.</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<a>` tag was not closed, so any text/code there after will be treated as sub-element of `<a>` tag, and hence you are getting the effect of `<a>` tag even after the `<nav>` tag.

NB: There is nothing special to `<nav>` tag. Don't blame that innocent. :P

**See there the running example of your code..**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.1/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <title>Example Cafe - community cafe in Newguay, Cornwall, UK </title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <section>
        <h1>Introduction</h1>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h1>Recipes</h1>
      </section>
    <nav>
    <p><a href="recipes.html">Recipes</a></p>
    <p><a href="men.html">Menu</a></p>
    <p><a href="operating_times.html">Operating Times</a></p>
    <p><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></p>
    </nav>
    <hr>
     <h1>EXAMPLE CAFE</h1>
    <p>Welcome to example cafe, We will be developing this site throughout
    the book.</p> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yep i'm hating the <nav> tag for no reason :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    You are not closing anchor tag, and remove <p> tag, it create subsequesnt line 
    every time
   <nav>
    <a href="recipes.html">Recipes</a>
    <a href="men.html">Menu<a/>
    <a href="operating_times.html">Operating Times<a/>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact<a/>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you! that was the problem! Have a nice day!